# Trying to encode GIF from raw bytes but it fails for larger images

Tags: python, encoding, encode, gif

I'm trying to write a gif encoder by writing the raw bytes to a file. I've been following the documentation [here](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt) and the Wikipedia page for [GIFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF). My code works for some small examples but I don't know why it fails for slightly larger images. My guess is that perhaps I have an implementation error with my LZW compression algorithm but I have no clue where it could be.

Note: The encoder is intended for a rather specific purpose so some of the code is just writing constants to the file because it won't be used outside of that scenario (unless the error is in the header section).

**My writer:**

```
class GifWriter(object):
    def __init__(self, output):
        self.out = open(output, 'wb')
    
    def writeHeader(self, width, height, bpp=4):
        self.bpp = max(min(bpp,8),1)
        
        self.out.write(b'GIF89a')
        self.out.write(width.to_bytes(2,byteorder='little'))
        self.out.write(height.to_bytes(2,byteorder='little'))
        b = 0xf0 + (self.bpp-1)
        self.out.write(b.to_bytes(1,byteorder='big'))
        self.out.write(b'\x00\x00')
    
    def writeApplicationExtensionLoop(self, loopCount=0):
        self.out.write(b'\x21\xFF\x0B')
        self.out.write(b'\x4E\x45\x54\x53\x43\x41\x50\x45\x32\x2E\x30')
        self.out.write(b'\x03\x01\x00\x00')
        self.out.write(b'\x00')
    
    # rgbIntArr = [r0, g0, b0, r1, g1, b1, ...]
    # 0 <= r*,g*,b* <= 255
    def writePalette(self, rgbIntArr):
        palette = np.empty((len(rgbIntArr)//3,3))
        i = 0
        for c in rgbIntArr:
            self.out.write(c.to_bytes(1,byteorder='big'))
            palette[i//3][i%3] = c
            i+=1
        self.paletteTree = scipy.spatial.KDTree(palette,copy_data=True)
    
    # image.shape = (w,h,3)
    def writeImage(self, image, delay):
        image = image[:,:,0:3]
    
        #Graphics Control Extension
        self.out.write(b'\x21\xF9\x04')
        self.out.write(b'\x00') #Packed Fields
        self.out.write(delay.to_bytes(2,byteorder='little')) #Delay time (1/100)
        self.out.write(b'\x00') #Transparent Color Index (not used)
        self.out.write(b'\x00') #Terminator
        
        #Image Descriptor
        self.out.write(b'\x2C') #Seperator
        self.out.write(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00') #Top Left Corner
        self.out.write(image.shape[1].to_bytes(2,byteorder='little')) #Width
        self.out.write(image.shape[0].to_bytes(2,byteorder='little')) #Height
        self.out.write(b'\x00') #Packed Fields
        
        
        #Image Data
        self.out.write(self.bpp.to_bytes(1,byteorder='big')) #LZW Minimum Code Size
        
        maxLen = 1
        currCode = 2**self.bpp+2
        dict = {}
        for i in range(16):
            dict[chr(i)] = i
        dict[chr(2**self.bpp+1)] = 2**self.bpp
        dict[chr(2**self.bpp+2)] = 2**self.bpp+1
        dataStr = chr(2**self.bpp+1) + "".join([chr(item) for item in self.paletteTree.query(image)[1].flatten()]) + chr(2**self.bpp+2)
        ind = 0
        
        bufferInd = 0
        buffer = bytearray(255)
        acc = 0x0
        accInd = 0      
        
        while ind < len(dataStr):
            for j in range(maxLen,0,-1):
                if ind+j <= len(dataStr) and dataStr[ind:ind+j] in dict and currCode < 2**12:
                    acc += dict[dataStr[ind:ind+j]] << accInd
                    accInd += (currCode-1).bit_length()
                    out.append(dict[dataStr[ind:ind+j]])
                    if accInd > 7:
                        buffer[bufferInd] = acc & 0xff
                        acc = acc >> 8
                        accInd -= 8
                        bufferInd += 1
                        if bufferInd == 255:
                            bufferInd = 0
                            self.out.write(b'\xff')
                            self.out.write(buffer)
                    
                    if not dataStr[ind:ind+j+1] in dict and ind != 0 and ind != len(dataStr)-1:
                        dict[dataStr[ind:ind+j+1]] = currCode
                        currCode += 1
                        maxLen = j+1
                    ind += j
        if accInd > 0:
            buffer[bufferInd] = acc & 0xff
            bufferInd += 1
        if bufferInd > 0:
            self.out.write(bufferInd.to_bytes(1,byteorder='big'))
            self.out.write(buffer[:bufferInd])
        
        self.out.write(b'\x00')
        
    def close(self):
        self.out.write(b'\x3B')
        self.out.close()
```

**Usage:**

```
import numpy as np

## Example 1
gif = GifWriter('e1.gif')
gif.writeHeader(3,5)

colors = [0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0xff]
a = np.empty((42))
a[0::3] = np.linspace(255,0,15)[:-1]
a[1::3] = np.linspace(255,0,15)[:-1]
a[2::3] = 0
for b in a.tolist():
    colors.append(int(b))
gif.writePalette(colors)

gif.writeApplicationExtensionLoop()

data = np.asarray([[[0x00,0x00,0x00],[0xff,0xff,0xff],[0xff,0xff,0xff]] , [[0xff,0xff,0xff],[0x00,0x00,0x00],[0xff,0xff,0xff]] , [[0xff,0xff,0x00],[0xdd,0xdd,0x00],[0xbb,0xbb,0x00]] , [[0x99,0x99,0x00],[0x77,0x77,0x00],[0x55,0x55,0x00]] , [[0x33,0x33,0x00],[0x11,0x11,0x00],[0x00,0x00,0x00]]])
gif.writeImage(data,100)
gif.close();


## Example 2
N = 5
gif = GifWriter('e2.gif')
gif.writeHeader(N,N)

colors = [0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0xff]
a = np.empty((42))
a[0::3] = np.linspace(255,0,15)[:-1]
a[1::3] = np.linspace(255,0,15)[:-1]
a[2::3] = 0
for b in a.tolist():
    colors.append(int(b))
gif.writePalette(colors)
gif.writeApplicationExtensionLoop()

data = np.empty((N,N,3))

data[:,:,0] = (np.flip(np.linspace(0,1,N))*np.ones((N,1)))*255
data[:,:,1] = (np.flip(np.linspace(0,1,N))*np.ones((N,1)))*255
data[:,:,2] = 0

data = data.astype(int)
gif.writeImage(data,100)
gif.close();
```

Example 1 from above correctly outputs the gif file [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HPuH.gif).
But Example 2 is incorrect as it outputs [Example 2 Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzR0x.gif) when it should look like [Example 2 Intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq62g.png)

Here is the hexdump if it is useful

```
Example 1:
           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   47 49 46 38 39 61 03 00 05 00 F3 00 00 00 00 00  GIF89a....ó.....
00000010   FF FF FF FF FF 00 EC EC 00 DA DA 00 C8 C8 00 B6  ......ìì.ÚÚ.ÈÈ.¶
00000020   B6 00 A3 A3 00 91 91 00 7F 7F 00 6D 6D 00 5B 5B  ¶.££..⌂⌂.mm.[[
00000030   00 48 48 00 36 36 00 24 24 00 12 12 00 21 FF 0B  .HH.66.$$....!..
00000040   4E 45 54 53 43 41 50 45 32 2E 30 03 01 00 00 00  NETSCAPE2.0.....
00000050   21 F9 04 00 64 00 00 00 2C 00 00 00 00 03 00 05  !ù..d...,.......
00000060   00 00 04 0A 10 84 09 82 20 06 A5 D5 1E 88 00 3B  ...... .¥Õ..;

Example 2:
           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   47 49 46 38 39 61 05 00 05 00 F3 00 00 00 00 00  GIF89a....ó.....
00000010   FF FF FF FF FF 00 EC EC 00 DA DA 00 C8 C8 00 B6  ......ìì.ÚÚ.ÈÈ.¶
00000020   B6 00 A3 A3 00 91 91 00 7F 7F 00 6D 6D 00 5B 5B  ¶.££..⌂⌂.mm.[[
00000030   00 48 48 00 36 36 00 24 24 00 12 12 00 21 FF 0B  .HH.66.$$....!..
00000040   4E 45 54 53 43 41 50 45 32 2E 30 03 01 00 00 00  NETSCAPE2.0.....
00000050   21 F9 04 00 64 00 00 00 2C 00 00 00 00 05 00 05  !ù..d...,.......
00000060   00 00 04 0C 50 98 D4 80 4C 55 CC 66 0D 05 B7 46  ....PÔLUÌf..·F
00000070   00 3B                                            .;
```